# How Can I show Profile information of the current user in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi all i'm completely new to ASP.Net and C# so will explain as best as I can what I am after. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (MSDNAA)

Basically I have setup up user registration and login using the wizard with the user data stored in aspnet_users table in the database ASPNETDB.MDF. I have also created in the data base a table called UserProfile with the fields, UserID, Address, Telephone, etc.

I have then created a relationship between the aspnet_users table and the UserProfile table by linking UserID.

What I am trying to do is create a profile page where users can insert and update their profile information. I have therefore created a page called userinfo.aspx and after following several tutorials, which often seem to be revolving around asp2, I have dragged in the FormView Option, and created a link to the database.

What I am stuck on is how I can get the current UserID that is logged on and display their information. My problem is under the WHERE option I cannot get it to use a current user as the source or is this totally wrong?

If you could advise me I would be grateful.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["USER_NAME"] = txt_uname.Text;
```

1. You have two forms userregistration and login form.
2. In user Registration you are inserting the details into database.
3. In Login Form, from textbox u will get the username and password. Check the username and password matching the Database. If it match then you have to maintain the username into session variable.